# Javascript Regex to validate single occurrence of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string to validate using javascript Regex. The string can have single occurrence of any different special character. I tried the following pattern.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]*[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]?[A-Za-z0-9]*$/
```

But it is allowing any two different special characters . But as per my scenario it should allow every special characters single time (eg. Single occurrence of '&' and '%' is acceptable but two occurrence of '&' or any other  is not allowed). Please help.

Comment: This regex pattern allows only one special character, have a look at https://regex101.com/r/cH7pV7/1

Comment: Is it possible to validate it using a single pattern. It will be difficult to get all the matching special characters from the string and find the duplicates manually. Even I'm not sure about that method and I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!.*([!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/-]).*\1)[!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/A-Za-z0-9-]+$
```

Try this.This will allow `special characters` `0 or more` but there will not be same `special character twice.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/5

```
var re = /^(?!.*([!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/-]).*\1)[!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/A-Za-z0-9-]+$/gm;
var str = 'abc12*$%\nabcd12324';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*whoops this is wrong*

That shouldn't be the case. You have something rather complex so try simplifying your regex to this:

`/^[A-Za-z0-9]*[\W_]?[A-Za-z0-9]*$/`

(`\W` includes all of those special characters except for `_`)

See if it's still not working

Comment: Oh I misinterpreted what you were saying. VKS has the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this gives the same result as my first pattern, and not allowing two different  special characters in the string. Can you please suggest me a pattern to validate my scenario. Any characters in the string but only one occurrence.